# Is it possible to install some cloud apps on Ubuntu?

Tags: dropbox

Is it possible to install cloud apps like Dropbox or OneDrive or Google drive on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Yes. See the individual questions linked above.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help you

- DROPBOX :- you can download it from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/install?os=lnx) or you can install Dropbox from Ubuntu software center of ubuntu
- Onedrive :- you can't install onedrive on ubuntu as it is Microsoft service.There is [project](http://xybu.me/projects/skydrive-d/) to port it to Linux but it is not ready yet.

you can use alternate cloud services as provided [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/130465/4-alternatives-to-google-drive-for-linux/)

Comment: Thank you, I think i will stick to Dropbox, though I prefer Google Drive, but I'm not very experienced Ubuntu user to do it via advanced options.